# Update Frontend after using Delete Route in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, crud, delete-file

I have created a delete route in express.js that looks like the following:

```
router.delete("/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log("delete route called")
    const noteToRemove = findById(req.params.id, notes);

    const result = notes.filter(note => note !== noteToRemove)
    
    console.log(result);

    fs.writeFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, '../../db/db.json'),
        JSON.stringify({ notes: result }, null, 2)
    );
)}
```

`findById` is a function I have declared in another file to locate an item in my database `db/db.json` that locates an item based on an ID I created earlier.

The issue here is that this code will remove an item from the database, but I want the frontend to show the updated list from the database. How does one reload the frontend to see the updated changes in the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How do you load the frontend to begin with, I mean, *before* the DELETE request is sent?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You will need to include a response in your server side method to let the client know that the resource was deleted. You should also add responses with error codes in cases something goes wrong, but for simplicity here we only address the nominal case.

```
router.delete("/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log("delete route called")
    const noteToRemove = findById(req.params.id, notes);

    const result = notes.filter(note => note !== noteToRemove)
    
    console.log(result);

    fs.writeFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, '../../db/db.json'),
        JSON.stringify({ notes: result }, null, 2)
    );

    res.end();  // respond to the client to let them know we are finished
)}
```

2. On the front-end you will need to react to this response and reload the resources. This highly depends on how your front end is structured and how it gets data from the server. As a hack, for now, you can just call [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), which will do the trick in the vast majority of cases -- but isn't very elegant of course nowadays where you could refetch and render just parts of the data and page.